# Removing child data from Firebase Database Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Please help me if possible. I want to remove data in the tableView when user calls the delete editingStyle function using the removeValue method. So far I have a class for the item:

```
class Item : NSObject {

    var itemName: String!
    var itemDate: String!
    var itemID: String!

    init(itemName: String, itemDate: String, itemID: String) {

        self.itemName = itemName
        self.itemDate = itemDate
        self.itemID = itemID



    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        self.itemName = snapshotValue!["itemName"] as! String
        self.itemDate = snapshotValue!["itemDate"] as! String
        self.itemID = snapshotValue!["itemID"] as! String
    }

        func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {
            return ["itemName": itemName as AnyObject, "itemDate": itemDate as AnyObject, "itemID": itemID as AnyObject]
    }


}
```

Now I want to delete the values inside the users itemID but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    let itemID = databaseRef.child("ItemID")

    databaseRef.child("users").child(uid).child("usersList").child(itemID).removeValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the "delete" editing style & the reference needed a little change. Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    let itemID = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("usersList").child("ItemID")

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        item.ref?.removeValue()
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not working it says an error saying "Expression type 'Void' (aka '()') is ambiguous without more context".

Comment: It's showing it in the last line for databaseRef.child...@Trev14

Comment: I made a few edits to my answer & didn't see any errors thrown in my firebase project as the code is now. Let me know if it works for you! @Chace

Comment: I had to change a lot of the project to get it to work as my dabaseref was not done properly. But I'm sure your method would have worked if I had coded the previous stuff better. @Trev14